# How can I make an input field read only but still have it send data back to a form?

Tags: html, css

I have an input field:

```
<input cid="Topic_Created" name="Topic.Created" size="25" type="text" value="6/5/2011 8:22:45 AM" />
```

I want the field to display on my form but don't want the user to be able to edit the field. When the user clicks submit I want the form value to be sent back to the server.

Is this possible. I tried different combinations of `disabled = "disabled"`, `readonly = "readonly"`. Seems I always get nothing sent back for the field.

Comment: You said that you tried `readonly="readonly"`. That should have worked.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Adding a hidden field with the same name will sends the data when the form is submitted.

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_name" value="blablabla" />
<input type="text" name="my_name" value="blablabla" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: This does not work at all. If you disable, then it will not be submitted with form. Instead, you will need to use readonly.

Comment: @DanStayntouch the disabled field doesn't send the data, the hidden one does.

Comment: So simple and yet so effective.  I'm kind-of embarrassed I didn't think of that myself! :-)

Answer (score 4):

alternatively u can make a little manipulation with javascript, remove the disabled property before form submitted

```
<form action="target.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="anu" name="anu" value="data anu" disabled="disabled" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('anu').disabled=''">send</button>
```

Comment: Terrible idea, user can hit Escape right before clicking Submit and modify the value.

Answer (score 4):

With Chrome browser on Windows 10 just having name="your_name" and the readonly attributes works fine: client cannot change a value, but it is sent to the server.

Comment: Same for IE 11 and Edge in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

On the assumption you're using a script to create the form, I'd suggest using `<input type="hidden" />` which will submit the variable with the form, but also use a regular `<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />` to show the variable to the user. This won't submit the value, obviously, but *will* make it visible (while the `hidden` input will submit the value, but not *show* the value).

You could also do this with JavaScript:

```
var theForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    if(inputs[i].type == 'hidden'){
        var newInput = document.createElement('input');
        newInput.type = 'text';
        newInput.setAttribute('disabled');
        newInput.value = inputs[i].value;
        theForm.appendChild(newInput);
    }
}
```

[Clumsy JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hzLVJ/).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function myFn(event) { 
        event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); 
    } 
</script> 

<input onkeydown="myFn(event)" >
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This code works because of you stop default action for keyboardevent (it is writing char)

Answer (score 2):

You can add 'readonly'='true' in the input element. With this the user cant edit and also send the value back to the server.

```
<input cid="Topic_Created" name="Topic.Created" size="25" type="text" value="6/5/2011 8:22:45 AM" readonly='true' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using input **type="hidden"** when submitting read-only fields. Otherwise, if you still need the value of input field to be visible, you should create another input (type=text) with a different name.

```
<input cid="Topic_Created" name="Topic.Created" type="hidden" value="6/5/2011 8:22:45 AM" />
<!--This is visible: -->
<input cid="Topic_Created" name="doesntmatter" size="25" type="text" value="6/5/2011 8:22:45 AM" />
```