# Making an input non-editable without disabling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form which calculates a cost and sets the value of an input accordingly. For obvious reasons, I have used:

`$('#totalcost').attr('disabled',true);`

to prevent the user from being able to edit the cost.

However, when I do this, the PHP script I'm using to mail the form doesn't pick up the input (not just the value - it doesn't read the input at all). When the input is enabled, it works fine.

How can I prevent the user from editing the input while still having the PHP mailing the value? Or is there a better way to do this anyway?

Comment: The values of disabled form elements are not send – this is explicitly _specified_ this way. Use `readonly` instead.

Comment: Well better place an hidden field also , this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241943/how-can-i-make-an-input-field-read-only-but-still-have-it-send-data-back-to-a-fo

Comment: Then again, inputs can still be edited after pressing submit, an example tool would be the Firefox extension: `tamperdata`

Answer (score 6):

Make it readonly, not disabled:

```
$("#totalcost").attr('readonly', true);
```

You could also do it in the original HTML, since it's not something you really want to change back and forth dynamically.

```
<input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm, thank you. Will accept when it lets me.

Comment: @A.Wolff, From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) it is attribute

Comment: @Murali ya but 'checked/disabled/etc...' are also attributes regarding MDN

Comment: @A.Wolff, then what is the use of introducing prop() by jQuery? confused :(

Comment: @A.Wolff The checked attribute specifies the initial, default state; the checked property is the current state of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Use Read Only property, Though i guess it wont work in internet exploer.

Answer (score 0):

Add readonly attribute, like this:

```
$("#totalcost").attr('readonly', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property readonly="true".

```
$('#totalcost').attr('readonly',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
$("#totalcost").prop("readonly",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use read only in html itself or in script

```
<input type="text" name="totalcost" id="totalcost" value="" readonly>

$('#totalcost').attr("readonly", true);
```